# HTTP Post with Volley gets NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'byte[] c.a.b.l.b'

Tags: android, android-volley

I use volley to send POST request to a webservice. It works good, but sometimes, I don't know why, I get this error and I don't know the reason and how to control it. I have ACRA enabled, and this is the main info about the error I get:

```
....
02-25 05:35:52.952 D\/InputMethodManager( 9979): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@72d70fd[ExportarDatos]
02-25 05:35:52.952 D\/InputMethodManager( 9979): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
02-25 05:35:52.968 E\/ViewRootImpl( 9979): sendUserActionEvent() mView returned.
02-25 05:35:53.194 D\/VOLLEY BODY SEND( 9979): {\"data\":{\"type\":.... rest of my json object}}
02-25 05:35:53.197 I\/System.out( 9979): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-25 05:35:53.197 I\/System.out( 9979): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-25 05:35:56.043 I\/System.out( 9979): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-25 05:35:56.043 I\/System.out( 9979): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-25 05:36:01.196 E\/VOLLEY  ( 9979): c.a.b.t
02-25 05:36:01.209 D\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): Process: com.mypack.myapp, PID: 9979
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'byte[] c.a.b.l.b' on a null object reference**
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat com.mypack.myapp.ExportarDatos$c.a(ExportarDatos.java:2)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat c.a.b.o.a(Request.java:7)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat c.a.b.g$b.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:6)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
02-25 05:36:01.211 E\/AndroidRuntime( 9979): \tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): ACRA caught a NullPointerException for com.mypack.myapp
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'byte[] c.a.b.l.b' on a null object reference
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat com.mypack.myapp.ExportarDatos$c.a(ExportarDatos.java:2)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat c.a.b.o.a(Request.java:7)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat c.a.b.g$b.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:6)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
02-25 05:36:01.213 E\/ACRA    ( 9979): \tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)",
...
```

This is the function to send POST/PATCH request to the webservice. As I said, It works good the most of the time, but sometimes I get the error, I don't know when nor why:

```
private void SendRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonBody, boolean lPost) {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        }

        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();
        Log.d("VOLLEY BODY SEND", mRequestBody);

        int nMetodo = Request.Method.POST;
        if (!lPost) nMetodo = Request.Method.PATCH;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(nMetodo, urlbase + url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                error.networkResponse.data.toString();
                try {
                    String body = new String(error.networkResponse.data, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d("VOLLEY_ERROR", body);
                    txtError.setText(body);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Accept", "application/vnd.api+json");
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/vnd.api+json");
                params.put("api-key", cparam);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                    Log.d("VOLLEY", responseString);
                    String json = "";
                    try {
                        json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                        jsonObjectRcv = new JSONObject(json);
                        // Process received object
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               ProcessResponse(jsonObjectRcv);
                           }
                        }, 50);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("VOLLEY", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        // Add to queue
        mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

The `urlbase` is the main url for the webservice. The url parameter is the endpoint+resource to POST/PATCH. The jsonBody is a JSON object that contains the info I want to POST or PATH, and It's right. I'm sure because it is include in the ACRA in the line:

```
02-25 05:35:53.194 D\/VOLLEY BODY SEND( 9979): {\"data\":{\"type\":.... rest of my json object}}
```

I think I have added all the information about my issue to get help, but ask me if I should add something more, and I'll update my question. I don't know what is throwing Nullpointer exception.

I would like to catch the error and let the user a way to retry. Now, ACRA error is launched and the app stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of test, fail, and research, the problem was `e.printStackTrace();`. I have erase this line and changed it with Log.e and the problem go out.